# Background image for rows and columns of boxes

Tags: html, css

The title isn't very descriptive, but basically I want to create something like this with HTML and CSS: [image: http://i.imgur.com/0fVLBrc.jpg]

I can do the horizontal line by wrapping the first row of boxes in a div and setting the background image for that to the line, but I'm not sure how I can group the column of boxes and add a vertical line behind them.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: One way would be to make a containing div with relative positioning using that dashed border image as the background image and then create 4 more divs inside of the container and absolutely position them accordingly(i.e. `top:0; left:0;`, `bottom:0; left:0`, `top:0; right:0;`, `bottom:0; right:0;`)

Answer (score 1):

Here you go [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/YoshiMaster/kxjezr5e/4/)

```
<div id="container">

    <div id ="horizontal">
        <div id="border2"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="vertical">
        <div id="border"></div>
    </div>

</div>

#container {background: black;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position:relative
}

#vertical {background: white;
    position: absolute;
    width: 70px;
    left: 40%   ;
    height: 300px;
    top:0;
}


#horizontal {background: white;
    position: absolute;


    height: 60px;
    top:40%;
    left:0;
    width: 100%;
}

#border {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;

    margin-top: 60px;

    border-top: 2px dashed black;
    border-bottom: 2px dashed black;
}

#border2 {
    width: 80%;
    height: 60px;


    border-right: 2px dashed black;
}
```